# Creating 3D using Qgis2Threejs

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, 3d

I have strange results when run Qgis2Threejs: used Google satelite, SRTM file in format .hgt, projections: 3857 and 4326 but didn`t receive 3D model.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

Change the value for "vertical exaggeration" within
qgis2threejs - Scene - Scene Settings

- for projection 3857 for example 100
- for projection 4326 for example 0.001 (point, not comma)